# How can I create a session to store the WhatsApp QR Code? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, session, qr-code, chatbot, whatsapp

So, I'm running an aplication kinda like a chatbot with WhatsApp but whenever I start the program I always have to read the QRCode. This is the beginning of the code:

```
const { Client } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const qrcode = require('qrcode-terminal');
require('dotenv').config()

const client = new Client();

client.on('qr', (qr) => {
    qrcode.generate(qr, {small: true});
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Client is ready!');
});
```

For example, what should I use to store the session so whenever I start the program it doens't require me to read the QR Code again?
I tried to use:

```
create({
    session: 'Chat-WhatsApp',
    multidevice: true
})
    .then((client) => start(client))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

But it failed.

Store the QRCode without the need of reading it again.